# Mail account of the Microsoft account not shown in Windows 10 mail

Tags: windows-10, windows-mail

This must be some stupid thing I overlook: in Windows 10 mail three mail accounts are shown, but I cannot select the account associated with My Microsoft account: It is not present. However, in the appointments the entries from My Microsoft account are present. Moreover, when I select settings and then 'accounts' the Microsoft account is shown and I can change its synchronization settings etc.

Wat do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed stupid. By default the synchronization of email is disabled for the Microsoft account. Turning this on solved the problem...